Ubuntu 22.04 - Python 3.11.9 no longer available by default?
Apologies if this is a dumb question. We used to have a dockerfile that used ubuntu:22.04 and it seemed to have python3.9.11 by default.
Just a couple of days ago, our CI/CD pipelines started failing because 3.11.9 was no longer available (by default?). Is there a way I can confirm what exactly changed in the last few days that started breaking us?
We are totally okay to upgrading if needed, just curious to learning more about how Ubuntu manages release updates.
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    libsnappy-dev \
    tzdata \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    python3.11=3.11.9-* \
    python3.11-distutils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Error:
37.10 E: Version '3.11.9-*' for 'python3.11' was not found



Ubuntu 22.04 used python3.10 by default...and nothing else. Your script shows that you added the deadsnakes PPA and then installed a bunch from that PPA. Looks like that's how you got python3.9

Sorry I edited the docker file, python3.11.9 is what I was referring to. @user535733 - I know it might be a long shot, but do you have a sense of what in deadsnakes PPA might have changed that 3.11.9 is no longer there?

First of all, your OP references 3.9.11 - is this a typo? Second, according to https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, deadsnakes updated their 3.11 release to 3.11.10 on 2024-09-07.

@ajgringo619 - yes that was a typo that was fixed. Do you know if there is a way to pin deadsnakes to 3.11.9?

If the repo decides to upgrade a package, and not keep any other revisions, then you're out of luck. If you need to run a python program on a fixed release, then I'd suggest looking into pyenv. FYI - python 3.11 is available for Ubuntu 22.04, but as of 2024-09-11 it's on version 3.11.0-rc1.
